# Why logging.warning("%s", s)?

Tags: python, logging

Can someone explaine the marked line of this method from `/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py`?

```
def _showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    """
    Implementation of showwarnings which redirects to logging, which will first
    check to see if the file parameter is None. If a file is specified, it will
    delegate to the original warnings implementation of showwarning. Otherwise,
    it will call warnings.formatwarning and will log the resulting string to a
    warnings logger named "py.warnings" with level logging.WARNING.
    """
    if file is not None:
        if _warnings_showwarning is not None:
            _warnings_showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file, line)
    else:
        s = warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line)
        logger = getLogger("py.warnings")
        if not logger.handlers:
            logger.addHandler(NullHandler())
        logger.warning("%s", s)  # <------ I don't understand this line
```

Why is the last line not this:

```
logger.warning(s)
```

Answer (score -2):

Because this is the correct syntax.
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

`Logger.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)`

`Logs a message with level WARNING on this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().`

This syntax is well known and used by all *printf() functions for example.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. OP asked why not just `logger.warning(s)`, which also matches the function signature.